# Error executing cl.exe

Tags: c++, crash

Trying to compile this game, And I'm getting this error:

```
Error executing cl.exe.
```

Here is the output log.
http://pastebin.com/qjjWr5tE

*The relevant information is:*

```
dragon.cpp
c:\documents and settings\xpmuser\desktop\client\dragon.cpp(13) : fatal error C1083:
    Cannot open include file: 'FPS.h': No such file or directory
```

Here is the main header.

http://pastebin.com/AyvUKen7

Comment: You don't get any other, more detailed error messages ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You've provided absolutely no useful information here; it's virtually impossible to help you solve your problem. There's no context, no actual error information, no source code, no makefile or command line used... Please edit your question to provide more information, and while doing so remember that we have no way to see your screen, read your code (or your mind), or by any other means get information other than what you provide us. If you want help solving your problem, you need to give us the information to use to provide it. Help us help you. Thanks. :)

Comment: It wouldn't allow me to post more Information for what ever reason!, I can provide the source.

Answer (score 2):

Given the error message:

```
dragon.cpp
c:\documents and settings\xpmuser\desktop\client\dragon.cpp(13) : fatal error C1083:
    Cannot open include file: 'FPS.h': No such file or directory
```

The problem is that your code in `dragon.cpp` includes a line:

```
#include "FPS.h"
```

and the compiler is unable to find a header of that name.

Review the file `dragon.cpp` and decide whether it really needs `FPS.h`.  If not, remove the line.  If it does, you must locate the file.  None of the other files you're compiling seem to use it, so it is not clear whether you really need it or not.